# Default login ubuntu on Raspberry pi for Turtlebot3

Tags: raspberry-pi, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to boot into my Raspberry Pi 3b+ on my Turtlebot3 with the respective image (https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/sbc_setup/#sbc-setup).
I get to the point where I need to enter the login information, but ubuntu/ ubuntu doesn't work. I have also tried pi/ raspberry etc. but nothing is correct.

Am I missing something? Is the username and pw for this image different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did a manual SBC setup, it took a while but worked out.

Update:
At least for the Melodic version

user = "ubuntu" and password = "turtlebot"